# MySQL Log file performance / size

Tags: mysql

Last week I noticed after a crash that my mysql log file had become so large that it consumed the disk - not a massive disk. I recently implemented a new helpdesk/ticketing system which was adopted by the entire company much quicker than was anticipated thus a log file with 99% selects.

So my question is this; Can I retain mysql logging but exclude select statements? Further more can I keep select statements but exclude certain databases(i.e. helpdesk)?

Thanks for any response

Comment: If you cannot, then you could fashion something to approximate it. Efficient use of `logrotate` and clearing all selects from the rotated file using `postrotate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict MySQL General log file to certain database or certain DML statements. It logs everything being executed on your MySQL server and ofcourse it's a overhead on a MySQL server in production environment.

I suggest you to turn-off General log on production server and enable slow query log with appropriate settings so that only problamatic queries will be logged which needs attention, later you can optimize those queries to achieve better MySQL performance.

If you still needs general log to be enabled then make sure that logrotate script is used for General log file which will keep it's size to a certain limit. 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: IME, the slow query log should be recording *every* query (which makes the general log somewhat redundant) restricting it to the slow queries gives a very distorted view of the performance and leads to bad tuning decisions: the right solution is to use logrotate.